# Building dataframe column wise or row wise?

Tags: pandas

I have to build a new data frame as output of my python program, this dataframe is dependent on previous columns, for example column 1and 2 will define items in col3 and further col4 is using previous cols. In total I would have 7 cold in dataframe.
How shall I build it col by col or row by row?

Answer (score 1):

You should build it column by column.

```
df[col_3] = func(df[col_1], df[col_2])
df[col_4] = func(df) # The dataframe inherently includes columns 1 and 2 and 3
df[col_5] = func(df)
...
```

et cetera.

If you're applying functions along the vector, row-wise make sure `axis=1` if that is an optional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two columns already available and looking to adding new columns, you should proceed by adding one new column at a time.

Column operations in pandas are straight forward.

http://queirozf.com/entries/pandas-dataframe-examples-column-operations has few simple examples of column operations with pandas.